# image isnt showing on layout preview in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

Am new to app development , however I have seen multiple sources online that show you how to add an image to your layout

However the image isnt being shown on the layout preview

My code is below

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/mm"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="132dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
```

I just don't know what I'm doing wrong .. I've followed multiple guides but still nothing

Image screenshot of studio showing issue :
https://imgwiz.com/image/gzHD

My PC seems to be having issues freezing occasionally whe Android studio is running so am setting up a VPS with studio on it and will test all these suggestions on the new installation as that may be related to my issue

Comment: Try Changing app:srcCompat="@drawable/mm"  to android:src="@drawable/mm"

Comment: tried this and no change

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/mm"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="132dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
```

instead of

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/mm"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="132dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
```

helped me.
You can replace it without any changes in your code.

In addition: Be aware of using

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="132dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
```

The namespace `tools:` means that it only affects your editor preview. As i saw in your screenshot, you are using a `ConstraintLayout` as parent layout. Consider adding `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf` etc to align your `ImageView`.

Comment: might seem a very daft question but how do i do that ?

Comment: Cheers, have made changes but still no difference

Comment: I also haae this in the bottom of the message window, dont know if its relevant or not to this error

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your ImageView's position is not in the viewing area of the Design/BluePrint

so I recommend to switch to Text mode
and add these to your ImageView

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
```

to make it show on the designer when move it to your desired position